Manipulating iptables on Docker Desktop VM
I'm using Docker Desktop on MacOS to run some tests. My containers are communicating with each other using their own network. I would like to be able to prevent containers establishing connections to the host. Connections must still be able to be established from the host to the container's network.
I was hoping to be able to just use iptables on the Docker Desktop Linux VM to achieve this, but iptables doesn't seem to be available on this VM. IIRC older versions (3.x?) of the Docker Desktop Linux VM did expose iptables, but I don't see anything equivalent on my current version (4.30.0).
Any thoughts on how to do this?
Update: Alternatively I guess I could also try and do this on my Mac as well - i.e. prevent incoming connections from the Docker Desktop VM. I'm running Sonoma (14.6)
